# xsl variable not passing values in

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:param name="contextPath">CONTEXT_PATH/</xsl:param>
<xsl:include href="xhtml.xsl"/>
<xsl:variable name="site"><xsl:value-of select="/leftnavigation/tree/path/node[2]/@name"/></xsl:variable>

        <xsl:template match="leftnavigation">
           <xsl:element name="h1">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">banner</xsl:attribute>

                        <xsl:apply-templates select="bannerleftimage" />
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="bannermiddleimage" />
                        <xsl:if test="$site='Families'">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="bannerrightimage" />

                            <!-- Just to output the value for dev purposes -->
                            <xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$site"/></xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>

            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">left_col</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="sectionlist" />
            </xsl:element>
            </xsl:template>

           <xsl:template match="bannerleftimage">           
            <xsl:variable name="currentsrc" select="@filename"/>
            <xsl:variable name="origwidth">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@width"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:variable name="origheight">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@height"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:variable name="ratio">
                <xsl:value-of select="$origwidth div $origheight"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
             <xsl:variable name="origalt">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@alt"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
             <xsl:variable name="origtitle">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@title"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:element name="a">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="$contextPath"/>/home.html</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="img">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$contextPath"/>/images/banners/<xsl:value-of select="@filename"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="width">365</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="height">100</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="$origtitle"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of select="$origalt"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="bannermiddleimage">            
            <xsl:variable name="currentsrc" select="@filename"/>
            <xsl:variable name="origwidth">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@width"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:variable name="origheight">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@height"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:variable name="ratio">
                <xsl:value-of select="$origwidth div $origheight"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
             <xsl:variable name="origalt">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@alt"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
             <xsl:variable name="origtitle">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@title"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:element name="a">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="$contextPath"/>/home.html</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="img">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">banmiddle</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$contextPath"/>/images/banners/<xsl:value-of select="@filename"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="width">1</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="height">100</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="$origtitle"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of select="$origalt"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="bannerrightimage">  
            <xsl:variable name="currentsrc" select="@filename"/>
            <xsl:variable name="origwidth">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@width"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:variable name="origheight">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@height"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:variable name="ratio">
                <xsl:value-of select="$origwidth div $origheight"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
             <xsl:variable name="origalt">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@alt"/>  
            </xsl:variable> 
             <xsl:variable name="origtitle">
                <xsl:value-of select="//gallery/image[@filename=$currentsrc]/@title"/>  
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">bannerright</xsl:attribute>            
                <xsl:element name="div">
                  <xsl:attribute name="id">talktoexpert</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="title">Talk to a specialist consultant</xsl:attribute>
                  Talk to a specialist consultant
                </xsl:element> 
                <xsl:element name="div">
                  <xsl:attribute name="id">bannertel</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="$origtitle"/></xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="../telephone"/>
                </xsl:element>    
                <xsl:element name="div">
                      <xsl:attribute name="id">bannertelint</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="$origtitle"/></xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:value-of select="../telephoneint"/>
                </xsl:element> 
            </xsl:element> 
        </xsl:template> 


        <xsl:template match="sectionlist">

        <xsl:element name="ul">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">side_menu</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="section">
                <xsl:element name="li">
                    <xsl:if test="@cssclass">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="@cssclass"/></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="@cssid">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@cssid"/></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I'm trying to set a condition around a template(`bannerrightimage`) to not appear for a specific brand(in your case the String) called `'Families'`. The `@name` usually returns three strings, `Families`, `Children`, `Adults`. And it works in my other xsl files.

The issue I'm having is that the variable `$site` is not passing in any values. but if I had something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="site"><xsl:text>ABC123</xsl:text>
```

`$site` does output ABC123. As I mentioned before, if I'm in home.xsl I would have my variable as:
**home.xsl**

```
<xsl:variable name="site"><xsl:value-of select="/home/tree/path/node[2]/@name"/>
```

and if it's **country.xsl** I would set my variable as:

```
<xsl:variable name="site"><xsl:value-of select="/country/tree/path/node[2]/@name"/>
```

home.xsl and country.xsl work perfectly fine but when I implement the same style for my **leftnavigation.xsl** `$site` is not returning any value. not even an empty space...

Comment: Since it looks like you're not selecting anything in your source XML, it would help if you also showed some of the XML that you're working with.  Also, your code fragments for `$site` would make more sense if you included the end tags.  Thirdly, `<xsl:variable name="site"><xsl:text>ABC123</xsl:text></xsl:variable>` could be `<xsl:variable name="site" select="'ABC123'"/>` and `<xsl:variable name="site"><xsl:value-of select="/home/tree/path/node[2]/@name"/></xsl:variable>` could be `<xsl:variable name="site" select="/home/tree/path/node[2]/@name"/>`

Comment: @TonyGraham I've edited the post so that the source can include everything I'm calling and using. Also I tried all those styles in terms of having it like `<xsl:variable name="site" select="'ABC123'"/>` as you mentioned. But after trying like 5000 times I ended up with that ridiculous convention and I left it in that state (for now).

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to see your well-formed source XML that starts with `<leftnavigation>` and includes down to the second `<node>` so we can see how well your XPath matches your structure.

Answer (score 1):

HUGE THANKS TO @Tony Graham !! When you mentioned "XPath matching structure" I realised I had not checked my leftnavigation.xml file. And I realised that in all the other xml files, they have a 'COMMON' section in their `xsd`s which includes nodes, of which I was looking for. However, in my `leftnavigation.xsd` file, it doesn't have that section hence when I was looking for nodes I was looking for ..well [NULL].

So here is what I find out, the `home-example.xml` file looks for a `noNamespacesSchemaLocation="home.xsd"`


So within the xml file the section I was looking for is the nodes section which is below.

**home-example.xml:**

```
<path>
        <node name="root" url="" type="ROOT" mainimage=""/>
        <node name="Wildlife" type="SITE" mainimage=""/>
        <node name="2006" type="VERSION" mainimage=""/>
        <node name="homepages" type="SECTION" mainimage=""/>
        <node name="First Home Page" url="/home/home.html" mainimage=""/>
    </path>
```

So within the xsd, there is a `Commons` section which looks like:

**home.xsd:**
================ Common ==================================

```
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:element name="node">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element ref="xhtml"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="url" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="abstract" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="mainimage" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="metadata" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="sectionimg">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="alt" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string"/>           
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="treeType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="parent">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="node" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="children">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="siblings">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="path">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

However, in my leftnavigation-example.xml and in my leftnavigation.xsd, I did not have both the commons section in the xsd and the nodes section in my xml therefore when I tried calling the variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="site"><xsl:value-of select="/leftnavigation/tree/path/node[2]/@name"/></xsl:variable>
```

I was getting nothing returned because the value of the selected path did not exist.

Thanks again to @tony graham for pointing me in the right direction....